# Information and tutorials about developing a SharePoint Service Application 

Tags: service-application, tutorials

I'm looking for information and tutorials on how to develop a SharePoint Service Application with the SharePoint Service Application Framework. The Internet seems to be full with information about how to configure the oob Service Applications but offers only very little information about how to develop a custom Service Application.

Where can I find resources mainly tutorials on this topic? Does anyone can provide me some links?

Bye, Flo

Answer (score 2):

Check out Andrew Connells video as part of the Channel 9 series

http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/SharePoint2010Developer/ServicesArchitecture/CreatingCustomServiceApplications

And labs
http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/SharePoint2010Developer/ServicesArchitecture

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but it's still relevant. I recently posted a tutorial series here on building service applications: http://www.mattjcowan.com/funcoding/tag/mycorp/